# Concurrent long-polling function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a simple function that long-polls to the server and just prints out response to the console.

I am not javascript developer and callbacks confuse me.

This code works:

```
const addr = "http://localhost:8080/action"

function longPoll(urls) {
  try {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", urls, false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
    console.log(xhttp.response);
    longPoll(urls)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    longPoll(urls)
  }
};

longPoll(addr);

console.log("end")
```

but, "end" is never printed.

What is the most simple way to run longPoll() concurrently, while the page is open?

edit:

With a help from comments i have changed the code which seems to be working as expected:

```
const addr = "http://localhost:8080/action"

function poll() {
  (async () => {
    const response = await fetch(addr)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)

    setTimeout(poll, 2000)

  })()

}

poll();

console.log("end")
```

Comment: You're using a synchronous request (the `false` in the call to `open`) - [you probably don't want to do that](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning).  If you're having problems using callbacks, perhaps show what you've tried in that area, since that's the better approach here.

Comment: just an observation: i am amateur go programmer, with very little javascript experience. Go concurrency syntax is so simple compared to js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the callback in a timeout so it doesn't block the main thread. The following code calls longPoll approximately every 200 milliseconds

```
const addr = "http://localhost:8080/action"

function longPoll(urls, delay = 5000) {
    try {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", urls, false);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
        xhttp.send();
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
        console.log(xhttp.response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }

    setTimeout(longPoll, delay, urls, delay)
};

longPoll(addr, 200); // a call delay in milliseconds

console.log("end")
```

Comment: Why the downvote? OP is calling `longPoll` recursively and never returning. SetTimeout allows the code to continue executing while still polling for new data at the specified rate.

Comment: This actually seems to solve the problem. "end" is printed and the polling continues. Thanks!

Comment: `setTimeout` does not use a new thread. It schedules the work to be done on the same thread at a later time.

Comment: This is still using a synchronous request, which will block all other JS running while the requests completes.  Given it's intention to be used as a long polling request, it makes this approach even worse - the entire UI could end up blocked for a long time while the request is completing.

Comment: true, it does block the ui. I am looking into how to make it async

Comment: @JamesThorpe My bad. I didn't notice OP was using a synchronous request as I'm used to using the Fetch API at this point and it didn't occur to me that anyone would still use synchronous XHR. This approach should be fine if using an async request. My main point is that the timeout allows the code to continue executing as it is no longer infinitely recurses without returning.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I never claimed it did. I meant that the recursive calls that don't return block the main thread so calling the function in `setTimeout` would allow the thread to continue executing until the timeout is triggered.

Comment: i added changed code to the main post with fetch api. setTimeout calls function recursively which solved my problem!